# How to listen to supabase realtime changes when a column parent is null?

Tags: postgresql, real-time, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I am trying to listen to supabase realtime changes when parentTodos is null. How can I do that?

```
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js')

const supabase = createClient(process.env.SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_KEY, {})

// Set your custom JWT here
supabase.realtime.setAuth('your-custom-jwt')

const channel = supabase
  .channel('db-changes')
  .on(
    'postgres_changes',
    {
      event: '*',
      schema: 'public',
      table: 'todos',
      filter: 'parent IS NULL',
    },
    (payload) => console.log(payload)
  )
  .subscribe()
```

This is not working whereas, removing the filter listens to all changes in the todos table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is` filter is currently not supported on Supabase realtime, so if you want to do this, you would have to listen to all changes, and just filter out the ones that have values on `parentTodos` column on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working because there seems to be a mismatch in your column name, you should correct your `filter` condition to `parentTodos`, you can try to modify your code to be;

```
const { createClient } = require('@supabase/supabase-js')

const supabase = createClient(process.env.SUPABASE_URL, process.env.SUPABASE_KEY, {})

// Set your custom JWT here
supabase.realtime.setAuth('your-custom-jwt')

const channel = supabase
  .channel('db-changes')
  .on(
    'postgres_changes',
    {
      event: '*',
      schema: 'public',
      table: 'todos',
      filter: 'parentTodos IS NULL',
    },
    (payload) => console.log(payload)
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right.Currently, supabase realtime doesn't support null filters. They may introduce it in the future. For more information, checkout this issue. https://github.com/supabase/realtime/issues/659#issuecomment-1707317519